# Database interface using inheritance and templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am trying to implement a simple database interface than can handle different types, including custom classes. I wanted to pick inheritance or templates but it seems that I used both with no good results.

**Header file**

```
enum class RECORD_TYPE
{
    TYPE_LONG = 11,
    TYPE_STRING = 12
//other types
};

// the reason I created this class is to use it as function member parent 
class RecordType
{
public:
    RecordType(RECORD_TYPE record_type) : record_type_(record_type) {}
    RECORD_TYPE get_record_type()
    {
        return record_type_;
    }

protected:
    RECORD_TYPE record_type_;
};

template<class T>
class RecordType_t : public RecordType
{
public:
    RecordType_t(T value, RecordType type) : RecordType(type), value_(value) {}
    const T &get_value() const { return value_; }

protected:
    T value_;
};

class RecordType_long : public RecordType_t<long>
{
public:
    RecordType_long(long value) : RecordType_t(value, RECORD_TYPE::TYPE_LONG) {};
};

class RecordType_string : public RecordType_t<std::string>
{
public:
    RecordType_string(std::string value) : RecordType_t(value, RECORD_TYPE::TYPE_STRING) {};
};
```

**Usage**

```
void add_record(const RecordType &record)
{   
    //here I need to know the type(string/long/custom) because the types have to be stored different
    switch (record.get_record_type())
    {
    case RECORD_TYPE::TYPE_LONG:
        //long x = record.get_value();

    case RECORD_TYPE::TYPE_STRING:
        //string x = record.get_value();
      //then do something with these values
    };
};

Database db;
RecordType_string str("test");
db.add_record(str);
RecordType_long lng(200);
db.add_record(lng)
```

My main problem (apart from the fact that I am pretty sure it's bad design) is that in the function add() I don't have access to get_value() member function so I can get the values of each type. Because, of course, in the parent class, if I create the get_value(), I won't know what type to return. 
Can you suggest how to implement better this thing?

Thank you

P.S. I could dynamically cast from RecordType into RecordType_long/RecordType_string/etc but I read here that this is really really bad design.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that templates provide a polymorphic behavior which is orthogonal to the one provided by inheritance.

The former provides [parametric polimorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism) while the latter provides [subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping).

These two different types of polymorphism doesn't mix together in C++. Each template specialization is a different type which is orthogonal to the others specialization of the same template, which means that there is no [*is-a*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship between such types as you have with inheritance.

So your choices really depend on the design you intend to use. To let each kind of field save itself on the database for example you would need to let each instance manage its own serialization without the need of knowing which is who, for example:

```
class SerializableRecord
{
public:
  virtual void save(Database& db) const;
}

class RecordType_long : private RecordType_t<long>, public SerializableRecord
{
public:
  void save(Database& db) const override {
    long value = get_value();
    /* save it on database somehow */
  }
}
```

In this way you can use polymorphism and templates together but for two different purposes, without the need of knowing which specific kind of record you are going to save, of course this also implies that you need to work with pointers or object slicing occurs.

Another solution would be to make `Database::save` templated and specialize for various types:

```
class Database {
  public:
    template<typename T> void save(const T& record);
}

template<> void Database::save<RecordType_t<long>>(const RecordType_t<long>& record) {
  long value = record.get_value();
  // ...
}
```

Actually you have many options, it really depends what you need to achieve and the complexity of the structure itself.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I thought myself about the first solution, so the RecordType has a save function with the DB as parameter, and not the other way. Although from a design perspective, perhaps DB should be the "bigger" entity, having the insert/update/delete functions. I will try also the second solution, seems nice.:)